# Using sqlalchemy to import csv files into a postgresql but I'm getting an error referencing a data type that my table should not be expecting

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I'm using the to_sql function in sqlalchemy to import a large number of csv files into the following postgresql table:

```
    CREATE TABLE gp_times(

         index text PRIMARY KEY,
         month text,
         day text,
         yr integer,
         lge text,
         rnd integer,
         session text,
         trk text,
    
         pos text,
         rdr_num integer,
         f_name text,
         l_name text,
         nat text,
         team text,
         manu text,
         num_of_laps integer,
    
         run_num integer,
         f_tire text,
         r_tire text,
         laps_on_f integer,
         laps_or_r integer,
         lap_num integer,
    
         lap_time text,
         lap_seconds decimal,
         lap_valid boolean,
    
         pit boolean,
    
         sec_one text,
         one_seconds decimal,
         one_valid boolean,
    
         sec_two text,
         two_seconds decimal,
         two_valid boolean,
    
         sec_thr text,
         thr_seconds decimal,
         thr_valid boolean,
    
         sec_four text,
         four_seconds decimal,
         four_valid boolean,
    
         avg_spd text
         )
```

This is the imports and for loop I'm putting the csv's through:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
from SQL_Strings import *

password = input("\n\nPassword: ")
print("\n\n")

engine = create_engine("postgresql://postgres:7158@localhost:5432/MotoGP")
conn = psycopg2.connect(f"host=localhost dbname=postgres user=postgres password={password}")
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute(dropTimesTable)
conn.commit()
cur.execute(createTimesTable)
conn.commit()

fLis = getFiles(csvSesDir, f"*.csv")

for file in fLis:
    with open(file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        df = pd.read_csv(f)
    print(file)
    df.to_sql("gp_times", con = engine, if_exists = "append", index = False)
```

As best as I can tell, the first file is importing correctly, but in the first line of the second file, I encounter the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) invalid input syntax for type double precision: "30.580*"
LINE 1: ...'24.982', 24.982, false, '32.986*', 32.986, true, '30.580*',...
                                                             ^
```

Absolutely none of the columns in the table expect a 'double precision' data type.  The only data types that are expected are text, integers, decimals, and booleans.  I really don't know what's happening here.  The column that value should be going into should be expecting a text value.

Thanks for your time.

edit: The problem value is in the `sec_thr` column in the csv.  I've done a query on the database and verified that the first csv was imported perfectly.  I can also tell that similar values have been put into the database in that column accurately.

I'm a little embarassed to say, I don't know how to get the python to print the column that it's trying to add the problem value to.

edit 2:
What I know for sure, The first file is being imported without error and a select query shows that data is exactly as intended.   The column that the problem data *should* be  going into accepted the same type of data multiple times in that file.  So either my code will only work on the first file in the list, (unlikely as the second file does start and the value that raises the error doesn't occur until halfway through the 4th row of the csv).  Or the column that the value is trying to be entered into is being altered at some point inside the for loop.  Or that the table is being altered at some point in the for loop.

edit 3:

```
dropTimesTable = """
    DROP TABLE gp_times
    """

createTimesTable = """
    CREATE TABLE gp_times(

        index text PRIMARY KEY,
        month text,
        day text,
        yr integer,
        lge text,
        rnd integer,
        session text,
        trk text,
    
        pos text,
        rdr_num integer,
        f_name text,
        l_name text,
        nat text,
        team text,
        manu text,
        num_of_laps integer,
    
        run_num integer,
        f_tire text,
        r_tire text,
        laps_on_f integer,
        laps_or_r integer,
        lap_num integer,
    
        lap_time text,
        lap_seconds decimal,
        lap_valid boolean,
    
        pit boolean,
    
        sec_one text,
        one_seconds decimal,
        one_valid boolean,
    
        sec_two text,
        two_seconds decimal,
        two_valid boolean,
    
        sec_thr text,
        thr_seconds decimal,
        thr_valid boolean,
    
        sec_four text,
        four_seconds decimal,
        four_valid boolean,
    
        avg_spd text
        )
    """
```

Comment: I would tend to believe the error. You need to verify that you are inserting into the table you think you are. The possibility being that a table of the same name exists in another schema in the same database or that that you are not connecting to the database you think you are.

Comment: I took a close look at the code.  There's no reason that I could see that I would be connecting to the wrong database.  I still went into pgAdmin and dropped the one other server.  I ran the code again with no change.  If I had been connecting to the wrong server, the error would have changed at least.

I know that thinking that my code is right and the error is wrong is egotism, I just don't know what it is I'm doing wrong, and what's worse, I have no idea what to google.

Comment: Can you share the name of the offending column, and the output of `\d gp_con` from the psql console?  You can [edit] the question to add this information.

Comment: I'm going to sound dumb here, but I don't know how to get the column in python.  I can look at the offending csv and tell you it's in the sec_thr column, but if there's something happening in the python that I don't understand, I'm just not sure.

Comment: That should have been `\d gp_times`

Comment: Where should it be `\d gp_times` ?

What function would the `\d` serve?

I find it hard to believe that anything changing the way I connect to the database is the issue, considering that the first file is importing correctly and the issue is not with the very first value in the csv.

Comment: You really need to start from the premise that the error message is correct and work from there. As to `\d gp_times` that needs to be run in `psql`. While you are in `psql` also run  `show search_path` and  update your question with the result.

Comment: Why are you under the impression I disbelieve the error?

Comment: Dropping a server in pgadmin does nothing at all to your database, it just changes pgadmin's internal information about who is available to connect to.  Instead, rename the table you think you are inserting into, and see if the error changes to say the target table does not exist.

Comment: The following: 'Absolutely none of the columns in the table expect a 'double precision' data type. ... The column that value should be going into should be expecting a text value.' The point is work backwards from the error message being correct and find the point in the process that makes it correct.  The simplest explanation is that you are working with a version of the table that has a `double precision` field in it and this , `'30.580*'`, is an improper value for it.

Comment: That would be the simplest explanation if it were possible.  In trying to use the SQL vernacular, I miss spoke.  I deleted the other server.  I just spent the last hour un-installing and re-installing the database.  Same error.  I am not saying that the error is wrong.  What I'm saying is I don't know what I'm doing to make such a strange thing happen.  I guess all I can do is go through what I know for sure again.

Comment: You have two database connections in play and you are doing this `cur.execute(dropTimesTable) ...` against the `postgres` database and the inserting against the `MotoGP` database. What are  the drop and create table scripts doing? Is the database name really "MotoGP"?

Comment: Are you sure that csv is correct - it isn't missing a delimiter somewhere?

Comment: When I open it in exel, It's correct.  I just opened the file in notepad, and this is the problem value and the preceding and following value:    True,30.580*,30.58

Comment: The issue still remains that you are dropping/creating the table in database `postgres` and running the inserts in database `MotoGP`.